# How can I remove the telephone number and keep the address using formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can I remove the telephone number from the D columns while keeping the rest of the address?

- Some columns don't have a telephone number.
- Some columns have a space between telephone number.
- Some telephone number have 10 digits some 12.
- Some telephone numbers have spaces eg : 020 8133 7730, 0207 790 7070

[image: Excel Sheet]

I have tried

```
=LEFT(D2,MIN(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},D2),""))-1)
```

Also tried

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(ISERR(MID(D2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:100")),1)+0),MID(D2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:100")),1),""))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to use the new `LET` function:

```
=LET(x,TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D2,",",REPT(" ",99)),99)),y,SUBSTITUTE(x," ",""),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(-y),OR(LEN(y)=10,LEN(y)=12)),SUBSTITUTE(D2,", " & x,""),D2))
```

**Algorithm**

- `x` returns the last, comma-separated substring
- `y` returns `x` with the spaces removed.
- Check that `y` is a number and also has a length of `10` or `12`
- If we pass the check, replace in the main string `x` preceded by the `,`
- If not, just return the original string.

[image]

*If you do not have the `LET` function, you can try:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(-SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D2,",",REPT(" ",99)),99))," ","")),OR(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D2,",",REPT(" ",99)),99))," ",""))=10,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D2,",",REPT(" ",99)),99))," ",""))=12)),SUBSTITUTE(D2,", " & TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D2,",",REPT(" ",99)),99)),""),D2)
```

**NOTE** *based on comment changing the definition of a phone number*

If, instead of the phone numbers being **10** or **12** digits, they are **10-12** digits, then all you need to do is change the length check in the formula.

In other words, instead of

```
...OR(LEN(y)=10,LEN(y)=12)...
```

you use:

```
OR(LEN(y)>=10,LEN(y)<=12)
```

So, this would change the formula to :

```
=LET(x,TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D3,",",REPT(" ",99)),99)),y,SUBSTITUTE(x," ",""),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(-y),OR(LEN(y)>=10,LEN(y)<=12)),SUBSTITUTE(D3,", " & x,""),D3))
```

You can make a similar change in the longer formula if you are using that one.

Comment: +1 As I was not aware that LET has been released for all Office365 users.

Comment: ....................................me too!

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I'm on the monthly update cycle and have it. It would not surprise me if the 6-month update cycle did not.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld After I saw your answer, I checked and there it was. Now, it is time to have fun with it as the insiders did :)

Comment: it doesn't work for numbers having spaces eg : 020 8133 7730, 0207 790 7070

[link]
https://i.imgur.com/GHjd68Z.jpg

Comment: @bOI I can only go by what you write. It doesn't work on those numbers because they do not meet the specifications you provided. You wrote: "*Some telephone number have **10** digits some **12**.*"  The numbers you are complaining about have **11** digits.  Do you want to change your definition of a telephone number?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Apologies for not being accurate.

Comment: @bOI No need to apologize, but if you want to change your definition of a telephone number, you will need to let me know what the new definition is.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  telephone numbers are 10 to 12 digits long, eg  2075388887, 0207 5155966, 44207 5155966

 Some of the telephone number have spacing between them eg 020 8133 7730, 0207 790 7070

Comment: @bOI See the **Note** I added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

In `E2` formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(D2,MIN(FIND(", "&{0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},D2&", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9"))-1),"")
```

[image]